# Is there a way to reduce the amount of radio buttons shown on smaller screens and then cycle through them?

Tags: css, radio-button, responsive

this is my first time posting, I hope I respected all the guidelines. If not, I'm sorry!

I'm trying to create a responsive website design with the following specs: 
1. Large background image, that does not change
2. set of (not yet determined amount) radio(?) buttons below
  -> buttons need to be mutually exclusive
3. image overlay with some text, that changes when the respective radio button is pressed
4. when in mobile mode only two buttons should be shown at the same time and two arrows appear to cycle between all possible buttons.

My problem starts at 4):
- I dont have the faintest idea where to start
- I dont know if there is a name for this type of behaviour, that I simply never heard of (which makes googleing a little hard^^)

I thought about Flex-boxes, but all I could manage was to wrap the buttons, but thats not really the same as hiding them.
I also thought about making the buttons simply disappear (display:none), but I'm not so sure on how to do that. (maybe putting additional rules for the bootstrap classes?)

On top of it all, the design needs to be laid out in such a way, that the customer can decide how many buttons there will be, e.g. I have no way of knowing beforehand how many there are, nor can I group them by adding specific classes.

My Question alas is this: can I dynamically embed the radio buttons on slider pages, which i can scroll through, but only if it is in a small screen? (my guess is, this is not a simple css matter)

edit: specified question

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/82bfdd8cdc.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="">
    <div class="bg-screen">
      <img src="img/test.jfif" alt="  " class="bg-screen-img">
      <div class="bg-screen-textarea">
      </div>
      <p class="bg-screen-text dummy"></p>
      <div class="radio">
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="radio" />
          <div class="radio-box box-1">
            <i class="fas fa-socks fa-3x"></i>
            <span>Choice 1</span>
          </div>
          <div class="bg-screen-text text-1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Nulla at volutpat diam ut venenatis tellus. Odio ut sem nulla pharetra diam sit
            amet. Phasellus egestas tellus rutrum tellus pellentesque eu tincidunt.</div>
        </label>
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="radio" />
          <div class="radio-box box-2">
            <i class="fas fa-user-tie fa-3x"></i>
            <span>Choice 2</span>
          </div>
          <div class="bg-screen-text text-2">Sit amet facilisis magna etiam tempor orci eu lobortis. Consectetur lorem donec massa sapien faucibus et molestie ac feugiat.
          </div>
        </label>
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="radio" />
          <div class="radio-box box-3">
            <i class="fas fa-building fa-3x"></i>
            <span>Choice 3</span>
          </div>
          <p class="bg-screen-text text-3">Risus ultricies tristique nulla aliquet enim tortor at auctor urna.</p>
        </label>
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="radio" />
          <div class="radio-box box-4">
            <i class="fas fa-building fa-3x"></i>
            <span>Choice 4</span>
          </div>
          <p class="bg-screen-text text-4">Fringilla ut morbi tincidunt augue. Velit euismod in pellentesque massa placerat duis ultricies lacus. </p>
        </label>
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="radio" />
          <div class="radio-box box-5">
            <i class="fas fa-building fa-3x"></i>
            <span>Choice 5</span>
          </div>

          <p class="bg-screen-text text-5">Ut enim blandit volutpat maecenas volutpat blandit aliquam etiam.</p>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```css
input {
  display: none;
}

input+div{
  background: rgba(76, 175, 80, 0.3);
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

input:checked+div {
  background-color: green;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 1%;
}

/*removing clickability of text itself inside the labels for the radio-buttons*/
label span {
  /* Firefox */
  -moz-user-select: none;
  /* Internet Explorer */
  -ms-user-select: none;
  /* KHTML browsers (e.g. Konqueror) */
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  /* Chrome, Safari, and Opera */
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  /* Disable Android and iOS callouts*/
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}

label div i{
  margin: 15% auto;
}

input:checked~.bg-screen-text {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: -25% 10%;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.bg-screen{
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.bg-screen-img{
  margin: 3% 7%;
  height: 25%;
  background-color: grey;
}

.bg-screen-text {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  left: 7%;
  right:7%;
  margin: 0 10%;
}

.radio {
  position: relative;
  top: -150px;
  margin: 3% 7%;
  text-align: center;
}

.radio-box {
  position: relative;
  height: 170px;
  width: 170px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

.radio-box span {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(0, 90px);
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

Comment: You are asking many different things here... Bootstrap has build in support with `media queries`, those make it possible to have differences in design for different screen sizes.

Comment: You may try and search for 'responsive html slider' or something similar...

Comment: @Brainfeeder thx so far, I guess ill force the behaviour with the media queries, but a slider is the exact opposite of what I am searching. I need to slide the buttons with a fixed image, not the image itself. (or maybe i just misunderstood what you meant)

Comment: Some sliders work with HTML contents and/or images. So you can have slides with only a radio button inside. Another option is to have a div wrapping the radio buttons and make it scrollable to left and right, hide the scrollbar and make the (arrow) buttons scroll the div on click.

Comment: @Brainfeeder Thanks a lot. That was the clue i needed.-> See answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks!

I got it working with the help of slick carousel. (https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/)
This pretty much gave me all the functionality without having to code it myself.

Comment: That's slick ;)